# Error 500 Wordpress database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm getting a error 500 when i try to select something from the database:

I've test it without the select function and just return a random string and it worked. But when i try to get a value from the database i'll get an error 500.

This is the function:

```
public function seasons_rules($CheckIn)
{
        $Request = $this->db->get_results(
        $this->db->prepare(
        "SELECT A.rule_id
          FROM $this->booking_rules_seasons_table AS A
          INNER JOIN $this->seasons_dates_table AS B
          ON B.season_id = A.seasons_id
          INNER JOIN $this->booking_rules_table AS C
          ON A.rule_id = C.id
          WHERE ('%s' BETWEEN B.start_date AND B.end_date) OR C.all_seasons = 1
          ",$CheckIn), ARRAY_A);

$RulesIDs = '';

if ( ( $Request == NULL ) || ( count( $Request ) == 0 ) ) {
    return false;
} else {
    foreach ($Request as $response) {
        $RulesIDs .= $response['rule_id'].',';
    }
    return $RulesIDs;
  }
}
```

When i run the query directly into database. I'll get a result back so there isn't any errors in the query.

Comment: Try turning on the PHP error displaying
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

You should be getting something.

Comment: Thanks! it works now.. I had a Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object error. I included the config folder and it worked

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the variable inside the string in the wrong way.

If you want to pass a variable of an object inside a string, you use this syntax:

```php
echo "This is my string: {$obj->string}";
```

You're passing the variable directly without the braces.